# Azure logs: tracking InterSystemsId and IntraSystemId

Tags: azure

Within a typical Azure audit log, there are fields InterSystemsId and IntraSystemId.

I am trying to find information related to a suspicious log. How do I find more information associated with these specific fields?

I am unable to find any docs around how to investigate these fields. My google-fu has failed to yield any results.

Answer (score 0):

> azure logs: tracking InterSystemsId and IntraSystemId:

The `InterSystemsId` and `IntraSystemId` are the audit logs which may be specific for the few systems or user generated logs. You can obtain more information on this in the Azure AD audit logs by applying the necessary filters.

Search for audit logs in the Azure Portal. You will be able to see the list of activities and reports logged on each event.

To get the audit logs of a user/service principal/system, filter it with target as shown.

[image]

Filter it with the necessary target ID (User principal ID) and retrieve the log information in a detailed way.

[image]

Note: *If you still need more useful information about the suspicious log entry, you need to work with the application or system's owners or administrators.*